# unique constraints for multiple columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

Guys i have that table in DB

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
ID | COMPANY_ID | NAME | DESCRIPTION | BARCODE 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

i want to make a constraints that **unique barcodes should be enetered with same companyID** .... so how to do that in mysql ??

NB: i cam enter multiple company_id in the table

Comment: Can same company_id be entered multiple times in the table ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a Composite [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) on `COMPANY_ID` and `BARCODE`, to your table. This basically means that it **will not allow rows having duplicate combination of values**, for the said two fields. It can still allow duplicate values individually for either of them.

Eg: `(1, 'abc')` combination will not be able to exist in more than one row. However, `(1, 'abc')`, `(1, 'def')` can exist. So it allows duplicate values individually (`Company_id` in this example)

Do the following (change table and column name(s) accordingly):

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_barcode_company UNIQUE (COMPANY_ID, BARCODE)
```

Comment: but by this i can enter same barcode in same company_id and thats what i dont want to happen

Comment: @firstNamelastName No it wont allow same barcode for same company_id, because they will be duplicates then, and this constraint stops duplicate(s) to be created in the table

Comment: but it doesnt allow duplicates companyID !!!

Comment: @firstNamelastName It will allow. For eg: company id = 1, it will allow (1, 'abc') , (1, 'cdf'), (1, 'efg) etc